# Trying to add adb to PATH variable OSX

Tags: android, macos, adb

I am trying to develop for android and I want to add the `adb` to my `PATH` so that I can launch it really easily. I have added directories before by for some reason `adb` does not want to be found. This is very frustrating. Has anyone else had this problem before?

I created a file `.profile` and added the following to it.

```
export PATH = ${PATH}:/Users/simon/Libs/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools/
export PATH = ${PATH}:/Users/simon/Libs/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools
```

When I check my environment path I see the following:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Libs/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools:/Libs/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools
```

So I know that it is added to my `PATH` variable. Now when I try to run `adb` I get that it is not found.

```
-bash: ./adb: No such file or directory
```

This is very very frustrating. Could it be a problem with permissions? Has anyone had this problem with OSX and Android?

Comment: note: putting spaces before and/or after the equals sign causes problems. it should look like "export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/simon/Libs/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Why are you trying to run "./adb"? That skips the path variable entirely and only looks for "adb" in the current directory. Try running "adb" instead.

Edit: your path looks wrong. You say you get

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Libs/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools:/Libs/android-sdk-mac_x86/platform-tools
```

You're missing the /Users/simon part.

Also note that if you have both .profile and .bash_profile files, only the latter gets executed.

Comment: Tried both ./adb and adb.. Nothing, I have no idea what is wrong with this.

Comment: Where is adb supposed to be located? Check that it's there and that it has execute permissions (cd to the directory and do ls -l adb).

Comment: If I go to the directory I can run it no problem. Here is the output. -rwxrwxrwx  1 simon  staff  179312 28 Feb 02:48 adb

Comment: @LaC, missing execute permissions on the file would be reported with `bash: /bin/ls: Permission denied`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It turns out both .profile and .bash_profile were both there. I had the values in .profile and yea. Now it works. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @user569594: I don't like that your `adb` executable is world-writable. I wonder if Apple has modified `bash` to _not_ execute world-writable executables? Try `chmod 755 adb` and try again?

Comment: Works now, I just had two profiles. One over wrote the other. If anyone is doing this use .bash_profile to edit the path variable. I followed a different tutorial that said to use .profile

Answer (score 304):

### Add to PATH for every login

**Total control version**:

in your terminal, navigate to home directory

> cd

create file .bash_profile

> touch .bash_profile

open file with TextEdit

> open -e .bash_profile

insert line into TextEdit

> export
>   PATH=$PATH:/Users/*username*/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/

save file and reload file

> source ~/.bash_profile

check if adb was set into path

> adb version

---

**One liner version**

Echo your export command and redirect the output to be appended to .bash_profile file and restart terminal. (have not verified this but should work)

> echo "export PATH=$PATH:/Users/*username*/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
>   sdk/platform-tools/" >> ~/.bash_profile

Comment: The penultimate step in the above step is "Restart Terminal" :)

Comment: Restart terminal should not be necessary, reloading the file should be enough

Comment: Update: Probably it doesn't work for you because you are using multiple tabs. Every tab on your terminal has his own session. So reload the .bash_profile in the tab of the "adb version" command.

Comment: can use export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/ , just by copy and paste and no need to change the _username_

Comment: I removed the `sdk/platform-tools/` bit at the end, since this was giving me a bash warning in Android Studio.

Comment: I checked like 7 different versions of this tutorial. And I was only able to understand this one and what I am trying to do here! Great, It worked!

Comment: You can also do `source ~/.bash_profile` instead of restarting the terminal.

Comment: My adb command works after using first method, but working till the terminal is opened in the same session. As I close terminal and open new window, then again adb commands doesn't respond.

Answer (score 66):

## Alternative: Install adb the easy way

If you don't want to have to worry about your path or updating adb manually, you can use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) instead.

`brew cask install android-platform-tools`

Comment: Much, MUCH better then trying to fiddle with PATH, .bash_profile etc.. Thanks!

Comment: yup  c[_] ~  ᒡ◯ᵔ◯ᒢ

Comment: FYI, this now gives the error: Error: No available formula with the name "android-platform-tools". Use: brew install Caskroom/cask/android-platform-tools instead

Comment: @The Hungry Androider - fixed it

Comment: I haven't tried this but I'm wondering if one installs Android Studio as well as with Homebrew, wondering if this could create a version out of sync problem in the future... just a thought

Comment: If you have multiple installations, bash will just use one of them consistently (as long as your path is configured the same each time).

Comment: Best and easiest answer!

Comment: This works now: brew install --cask android-platform-tools

Answer (score 27):

On my Macbook Pro, I've added the export lines to ~/.bash_profile, not .profile.

e.g.

```
export PATH=/Users/me/android-sdk-mac_86/platform-tools:/Users/me/android-sdk-mac_86/tools:$PATH
```

Comment: funny. I opened up that file...This exact line was already in there. I think eclipse added that while installing the plug-in?

Comment: It is possible, though I added mine myself.

Comment: According to http://johnnywey.wordpress.com/2008/04/17/fixing-bash-profile-in-os-x/ you may have conflicting profiles

Comment: I think that's exactly what the problem was. Another app (I think MacPorts) created .profile

Comment: Don't forget to restart terminal after you add to PATH.

Answer (score 13):

Just encase anyone finds this SO post when using Android Studio which includes the SDK has part of the App package (on Mac OSX).

So as @davecaunt and @user1281750 noted but insert the following line to  .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools:/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Comment: Alternatively, it's located in Users/[user]/Android/sdk/platform-tools....  I don't like linking to the Applications folder (maybe that's just me though).

Answer (score 13):

**The answer for MAC should be:**

1. Open your bash_profile with the following commands: `open ~/.bash_profile`
2. In case base profile file doesn't exist, create a new one with the following command: `touch .bash_profile` then repeat phase 1.
3. Add the following line: `export PATH=/Users/"YOURUSER"/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH`
4. Restart your bash window and test by typing `adb shell`

Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 10):

In your terminal, navigate to home directory

```
cd
create file .bash_profile

touch .bash_profile
open file with TextEdit

open -e .bash_profile
insert line into TextEdit

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
save file and reload file
```

**source ~/.bash_profile** is very important
check if adb was set into path

```
adb version
```

It should be fine now.

Answer (score 8):

I use zsh and Android Studio. I use a variable for my Android SDK path and configure in the file `~/.zshrc`:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH"
```

*Note: Make sure not to include single or double quotes around the specified path. If you do, it won't work.*

Answer (score 7):

Android Studio v1.2 installs the adb tool in this path:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

So it goes like this:

1. Run Terminal
2. run `adb version` and expect an error output
3. `touch ~/.bash_profile`
4. `open ~/.bash_profile`
5. add the above path before the 'closing' :$PATH
6. `source ~/.bash_profile`
7. run `adb version` and expect an output

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you're still trying to execute `adb` with `./adb`. That asks the shell to run the program named `adb` *in the current working directory*.

Try just `adb` without `./`.

Comment: Tried that too. Nothing. This is seriously driving me nuts.

Comment: @user569594: did you re-start your shell after editing `.profile`? (i.e., if you `echo $PATH` before `adb`, do you see the new directories?)

Comment: yes, I mentioned that in the question. It shows up in the echo, bash for some reason just CAN NOT SEE IT.

Comment: @user569594: sorry, had to ask, I've seen people edit their shell start-up scriptss, test their changes by starting a new shell, and forget to re-start their current shell and wonder where it fails... :)

Comment: Yea, I made sure to restart. The problem lied in having two profiles in my home directory. A .bash_profile and a .profile

Comment: @user569594, cool! If that's the case, @David Caunt's answer looks like the one to `Accept`. :)

Answer (score 3):

In order to make the terminal always have the file `~/.bashrc` and there put the path you wish to use, by adding:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/XXX
```

where XXX is the path that you wish to use.

for adb, here's what i use:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/Android/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools/
```

(where "user" is my user name).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

2nd solution is explained below. But when i close the terminal the change which i made in path variable gets lost. Thus i prefer the first way!

[image]

Comment: First method work for me, then you need restart your computer

Answer (score 2):

If you are Catalina user follow this

1. Make sure to be in the Home directory

   cd ~
2. To persist PATH changes and prevent it to be cleaned up after closing the Terminal app, you need to keep the variables in the zshrc file for Catalina

   touch .zshrc
3. Open it with the TextEditor

   open -e .zshrc
4. Insert the command below to add ADB as PATH variable (replace username with your own)

   export PATH=$PATH:/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
5. Save the file and close the TextEditor app. Back to the Terminal app, insert the following to source the file

   source .zshrc
6. And you’re done! Let’s test if it was successful

   adb version
7. You should expect something like

   Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
   Version 31.0.2-7242960
   Installed as /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools//adb

Answer (score 1):

I added `export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/mishrapranjal/android-sdks/platform-tools/` into both places `.bash_profile` and `.profile` to make sure it works. Still it wasn't working and then I looked at [sarnold's tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5526493/1446834) about restarting terminal and it worked like a charm.
It saved my time of adding every time this into the `PATH` whenever I had to run `adb`.
Thank you guys.

Comment: Instead of relauching your terminal you can use the following command to reload the file: "*. .bash_profile*"

Answer (score 0):

If anyone can't seem to get there `.bash_profile` file to take any new Paths **AND** you have other commands in that file (like alias commands) then try moving the PATH statements to the top of the file.

That is the only thing that worked for me. The reason it worked was because I had some typos in my alias commands and apparently this file throws an error and exits if it runs into a problem. So that is why my PATH statements weren't being run. Moving it to the top just let it run first.

Answer (score 0):

In bash profile
just add -

> export PATH=$PATH:/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/

and then in terminal run -

> adb version

Answer (score 0):

All answers are well written and helpful but there is one thing that I want to mention. Before adding path variable to `.bash_profile` kindly check your default shell.

Because i was seting path variable in `.bash_profile` file but my default shell was `zsh` that's why i have to run `source ~/.bash_profile` each time before using adb command.

So first check your default shell:

```
echo $SHELL
```

- if the output is `/bin/bash` then you should set path variable in
  `.bash_profile`
- If the output is `/bin/zsh` then you should set path variable in `.zshrc`

And here is my path variable:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/Users/aliasjad/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$PATH"
```