# Android using SQLCipher - how can you decrypt?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlcipher

I think this question has been asked, however I have tried several of the examples to no avail.  My issue is this ... I have an Android app setup to use the SQLCipher DB encryption, which works fine, on the device.

In testing on an emulator, if I download the Database file using the DDMS, how do I read that file to check tables and data?  I have tried using the command shell for SQLite3, and the ATTACH examples, however each time I do so, I just get the following message 'Error: file is encrypted or not a database'.  This certainly shows that the ENCRYPT is working, but how I do I properly DECRYPT outside the emulator/eclipse?

Do I need a different SQLite client? Anyone else get stuck on this?

I a using: SQLCipher for Android 2.0.8 06/14/2012

Any help? Thanks

Comment: And what are you using on your development machine?

Comment: As in to try and read the encrypted file or for the Android development?  I have tried SQLiteStudio v2.0.28 / SQLite command shell 3.7.14.1 / and SQLite Manager for Firefox.   Dev. environment is Eclipse Juno, targeting Android min. API 8 for Android 2.2.

Comment: And do any of those advertise that they have SQLCipher support?

Comment: Yes, The SQLite command shell specifically shows examples for ATTACHing to SQLCipher encrypted DBs: http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api#attach

Comment: possible duplicate of [file is encrypted or is not a database (Exception net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062277/file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database-exception-net-sqlcipher-database-sqlitee)

Comment: see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132477/how-to-decrypt-an-encrypted-sqlcipher-database-file-on-command-line/

Answer (score 4):

The "normal" SQLite tools do not include SQLCipher.

You have to [download](http://sqlcipher.net/downloads) the souce and [compile it yourself](https://sites.google.com/site/lukeshq/engineering-articles/compiling-sqlcipher-for-windows) to get a command shell with SQLCipher support.

Comment: Ah, so to be clear - the 'Community' version can be added into an Android project and work just fine within the project; however to integrate into a SQLite client you would need to purchase the 'Commercial' version for those binaries to compile? Or can the 'Community' version be compiled into the existing shell?

Comment: Addition: thanks for the compile link, I'll work through that to see if I can get this working. So far that looks like what I need. So much for having a quick/easy solution available.  I'll add comment if I get stuck. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this by using this small script.

## decrypt.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bashscript to decrypt databases

echo "pull db from device.."
adb pull /data/data/com.example/databases/database.db

echo "removing previous decrypted db, if existent.."
rm -r decrypted_database.db

echo "decrypting database.db into decrypted_database.db"
sqlcipher -line database.db 'PRAGMA key = "encryption_key";ATTACH DATABASE "decrypted_database.db" AS decrypted_database KEY "";SELECT sqlcipher_export("decrypted_database");DETACH DATABASE decrypted_database;'
```

These programs should be added to your PATH:

- [adb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19764254/1281750)
- [sqlcipher](https://www.zetetic.net/blog/2013/1/21/sqlcipher-available-on-homebrew.html)

Replace in script:

- **com.example** with your packagename
- **database.db** with name databasefile
- **encryption_key** with encryption password