# SQLCipher change DB password with rekey

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, sqlcipher

I'm using SQLCipher on Android to get an encrypted database. The DB gets an default password which is based on some hardcoded value. The user can also set a pincode on the app. When a user does that I also want change the DB password being used by SQLCipher. I already found a few post on StackerOverflow said that I should use rekey.

Currently I'm using this code like the posts suggested

```
final DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
final SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase(oldPassword);
final String PRAGMA_KEY = String.format("PRAGMA key = \"%s\";", oldPassword);
final String PRAGMA_REKEY = String.format("PRAGMA rekey = \"%s\";", newPassword);
db.rawExecSQL("BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION;");
db.rawExecSQL(PRAGMA_KEY);
db.rawExecSQL(PRAGMA_REKEY);
db.close();
```

But when I try to insert into the DB after the password should have changed I get this error.

```
sqlite returned: error code = 26, msg = statement aborts at 1: [BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;] file is encrypted or is not a database
Failure 26 (file is encrypted or is not a database) on 0xb90048c0 when executing 'BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;'
FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[DBService]
    Process: com.example, PID: 26502
    net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE;
            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1831)
            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransactionWithListener(SQLiteDatabase.java:584)
            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:538)
            at com.example.db.Provider.bulkInsert(OurProvider.java:196)
            at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.bulkInsert(ContentProvider.java:250)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.bulkInsert(ContentResolver.java:1268)
            at nl.qbusict.cupboard.ProviderCompartment.put(ProviderCompartment.java:158)
            at com.example.db.DBUtils.saveObjects(DBUtils.java:32)
            at com.example.services.DBService.getDataFromAPI(DBService.java:119)
            at com.example.services.DBService.onHandleIntent(DBService.java:48)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I checked both the original password and the new password before and after the change they where all the same. I also tried adding `db.rawExecSQL("END;");` and `db.rawExecSQL("COMMIT;");` but that didn't help. Also I see a log msg come by `error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt` when I change the password. Don't know if that has anything to do with it?

```
public class OurProvider extends ContentProvider {
    @Override
    public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getDatabase().getWritableDatabase(getPassword());
            final String table = getTableString(uri);

            db.beginTransaction();
            int rowsInserted = 0;
            try {
                for (ContentValues value : values) {
                    db.insertWithOnConflict(table, null, value, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                    rowsInserted++;
                }
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Crashlytics.logException(e);
                Log.d(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                rowsInserted = -1;
            } finally {
                db.endTransaction();
                if (rowsInserted > 0) {
                    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
                }

            }
            return rowsInserted;
        }
    }

    private String getPassword() {
        final String password = Base64.encodeToString(OurApplication.getEncryptionKey().getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Log.e("SQLCipher_OurProvider", "SQLCipher password: " + password);
        return password;
    }

    private void initDb() {
        SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(getContext());

        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
    }

    public DatabaseHelper getDatabase() {
        if (mDatabaseHelper == null) {
            initDb();
        }
        return mDatabaseHelper;
    }
}



public class DBService extends IntentService {
    private void updatePasscode(Intent intent) {
        final SecretKey oldKey = OurApplication.getEncryptionKey();
        final String encryptedString = SecurePrefs.getEncryptedString(PrefKeys.ENC_CONFIRM);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(encryptedString)) {
            String decryptedString = Crypto.decrypt(oldKey, encryptedString);
            // check if the oldkey can decrypt the confirmation string.
            if (BaseActivity.CONFIRM_STRING.equals(decryptedString)) {
                String pin = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_PASSCODE);
                if (pin.equals(PasscodeActivity.REMOVE_PIN)) {
                    pin = null;
                }
                final SecretKey newKey = SecurityUtil.generateKey(this, pin);
                final String accessToken = getUserAccessToken();
                final String refreshToken = SecurePrefs.getString(PrefKeys.USER_REFRESH_TOKEN);
                final String email = SecurePrefs.getString(PrefKeys.USER_ID);
                final String confirmEncrypted = SecurePrefs.getString(PrefKeys.ENC_CONFIRM);
                // set the newly generated string in the application.
                OurApplication.setEncryptionKey(newKey);

                // clear the old encrypted prefs. save the values with the new encryption key.
                SecurePrefs.clear();
                SecurePrefs.putString(PrefKeys.USER_ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);
                SecurePrefs.putString(PrefKeys.USER_REFRESH_TOKEN, refreshToken);
                SecurePrefs.putString(PrefKeys.USER_ID, email);
                SecurePrefs.putString(PrefKeys.ENC_CONFIRM, confirmEncrypted);

                // update de encryption key in the database.
                final String oldPassword = Base64
                        .encodeToString(oldKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                final String newPassword = Base64
                        .encodeToString(newKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);

                final String PRAGMA_KEY = String.format("PRAGMA key = \"%s\";", oldPassword);
                final String PRAGMA_REKEY = String.format("PRAGMA rekey = \"%s\";", newPassword);

                final DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
                final SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase(oldPassword);


                db.rawExecSQL("BEGIN IMMEDIATE TRANSACTION;");
                db.rawExecSQL(PRAGMA_KEY);
                db.rawExecSQL(PRAGMA_REKEY);
                db.close();
                sendBroadcast(IntentUtil.createBroadcastPasscodeUpdated());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [file is encrypted or is not a database (Exception net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062277/file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database-exception-net-sqlcipher-database-sqlitee)

Comment: @maveňツ the database always has a password. It uses a hardcode one for when hasn't set a pincode.

Comment: error itself indicates `That File is not a database file`. pls share complete code.

Comment: @maveňツ okay added some extra code

Answer (score 2):

You should not begin a transaction (this is handled [internally](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher/blob/master/src/crypto.c#L440) and slightly different), nor do you need to perform the `PRAGMA key='…';` portion of your code either.  You can should just open the database with your call to `getWritableDatabase(…);` and then execute your `PRAGMA rekey='…';` command.

Comment: I removed PRAGMA key='…'; but it still doesn't work properly so I just simply get all the data from the DB and delete it then create a new one with the new key.

Comment: We have an example of rekeying a database within the SQLCipher for Android test suite [here](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests/blob/master/src/main/java/net/zetetic/tests/RawRekeyTest.java).

Comment: Hi Nick I tried this but it didn't work `sqlite returned: error code = 26, msg = file is encrypted or is not a database
CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed
Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database
    net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database`

Comment: Did you run the test suite?

Comment: no I will look into it when I have more time to debug this issue. the current fix works.

Comment: sorry for pointing this out this late, @NickParker the link is expired now.

Comment: For anyone hitting this page I believe this is the new link [HERE](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher/blob/master/test/sqlcipher-rekey.test)

Comment: The new links to the rekeying examples of SQLCipher for Android are [here](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/zetetic/tests/RawRekeyTest.java) and [here](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android-tests/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/zetetic/tests/support/RawRekeyTest.java).

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem and the reason turned out to be that the DB wasn't encrypted at the first place, so then `PRAGMA key = <new_key>` or `PRAGMA rekey = <new_key>` failed. So, the `oldPassword` CAN'T be null or empty.

Comment: Thanks I used and empty initial password:-)