# Copy sqlite in android studio assets not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

Using free DBBrowser(SQLite) software I can see the data inside the data.sqlite file but when I copy it to Android Studio Assets folder no matter what code I use I get one of two errors:
No such table Table1_Sheet1
or
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26): , while compiling: SELECT Column2, Column3, Column4,Column5,Column6, Column7 FROM Table1_Sheet1 WHERE Column1=?

One of the codes I try:

```
public class MyCustomDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private Context mycontext;
@Override public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
private String DB_PATH=""; 
private static String DB_NAME = "data.sqlite";
public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
public MyCustomDBHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
    super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
    this.mycontext=context;
   DB_PATH=mycontext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir+"/databases/";
    boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
    if (dbexist) {
        myDataBase=opendatabase();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        createdatabase();          
    }
}

public void createdatabase(){
        try {
            copydatabase();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
}

private boolean checkdatabase() {
    boolean checkdb = false;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH+ DB_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
                  checkdb = dbfile.exists();
    } catch(SQLiteException e) {
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    }
    return checkdb;
}

private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    FileOutputStream(mycontext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir+"/databases/data.sqlite");

    //OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(mycontext.getDatabasePath("data.sqlite").getAbsolutePath());
    OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0) {
        myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myoutput.flush();
    myoutput.close();
    myinput.close();
}

public SQLiteDatabase opendatabase() throws SQLException {
    //Open the database
    String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    return myDataBase;
```

}

```
public synchronized void close() {
    if(myDataBase != null) {
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
```

}

I get the error when I try to read data from the copied file.I also observed the copy loop doesn't take long time only few times around 7 times.
I also observed in the mobile I used for testing inside the data folder nothing is actually created for the project.
Last thing I observed the data.sqlite file inside Assets folder has question mark on its file icon does this means it is not identified by android studio ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062277/file-is-encrypted-or-is-not-a-database-exception-net-sqlcipher-database-sqlitee

Comment: I don't use sqlcipher  and I didn't use any password when creating the database.I will check if I have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Unfortunately I already have both read and write external permissions in my app manifest

Comment: I exported the database as .db but I get the same error.Since the read write permissions already exist and I don't know what should I do to find out what causing the problem.

Comment: use your logcat to see the errors

Comment: your errors are showing file is encrypted or database is corrupt you need to check your data base

Comment: otherwise send me the file i will check

Comment: I don't mind send you the file but I cannot upload it here for public.Can you give me your email?

Comment: usamaaltaf211@gmail.com

Comment: I sent the file to your email yesterday with title database file.Hope you find out what is the problem...

Comment: No such table Table1_Sheet1 why you are using Table1_Sheet1 there is no table available in your sheet use January_Sheet1  instead Table1_Sheet1

Comment: I'm using January_Sheet1 in  the code but I replaced it here to avoid showing the data in detail for the public.Did the file open with you using similar code or different code? was the file copied to the mobile successfully?

Comment: I really need your reply did the file work with you in the app? or it is corrupted?

Answer (score 1):

I found the following thread more helpful for my issue:
[How to use an existing database with an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application)
also the argument I was feeding for the cursor query was wrong.