# How to change .android folder path in Mac OS X?

Tags: android

I have another .android folder. How can i change the path of the .android folder in MAC OS X ? Is there any configuration changes required to change path like in Windows 7/8 ?

Thanks in Advance.

**EDIT**

I have .android folder which is inside c:\users\USERNAME.android in Windows 7 laptop. In Windows 7 there is **Environment Variable** option to set the another .android folder path. But if i want to do same in MAC OS X then how can i do that?

Comment: you mean android SDK folder path ?

Comment: please! elaborate your question.

Comment: .android folder which is exist in USERNAME/.android

Comment: @Lawrence check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526470/trying-to-add-adb-to-path-variable-osx) may help you.

Comment: Hey @RDC,here is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109473/moving-default-avd-configuration-folder-android) what i want in MAC OS.

Comment: I have the same question

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, and this is how I solved it:

First, copy the `.android` content to a new folder you want to move it to so that your new location will be like `/newFolder/.android/`.

Second, create a symbolic link from your home folder with this command

```
ln -s /newFolder/.android/ .android
```

Then, the system will go to the `/newFolder/.android/` whenever its look for `.android`

Comment: it is not able to launch avd with this approach.

Comment: It's works for me and i can run avd's without problem.

Comment: It not work for android studio download by July 24 2022