# -bash: ./android: No such file or directory

Tags: android, bash, path, android-studio

Im trying to create a jar file of Volley but i get:

```
=> android update project -p
-bash: android: command not found
```

Here is my PATH setup in my .bash_profile:

```
#   Set Paths
#   ------------------------------------------------------------
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/"
export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:/sw/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Applications/"Android Studio"/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

When I run env....and look at my PATH and ANDROID_HOME...it looks correct:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/Applications/Android Studio/sdk
```

`PATH=/Users/username/Applications/Android Studio/sdk/platform-    tools:/Users/username/Applications/Android Studio/sdk/tools:/usr/local/git/bin:/sw/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/`

Ive also tried using:

1. ./android
2. copying hprof-conv from /platform-tools to /tools
3. chmod 777
4. ls -l ~/Applications/Android\ Studio/sdk/tools/android update project -p
   ls: -p: No such file or directory
   ls: /Users/username/Applications/Android Studio/sdk/tools/android: No such file or directory
   ls: project: No such file or directory
   ls: update: No such file or directory
5. => ls -l ~/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk/tools/android update project -p
   ls: -p: No such file or directory
   ls: /Users/username/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/tools/android: No such file or directory
   ls: project: No such file or directory
   ls: update: No such file or directory

Im going crazy over here....Im hoping there is something wrong with the way my PATH is setup, otherwise I dont know what to try next.

Please Help.

Comment: are you sure the folder `/Users/username/Applications/Android Studio/sdk` exists?

Comment: Yes.  I am able to double click on the android executable file from that location:  `/Users/username/Applications/Android Studio/sdk/tools`

Comment: What if you try to run it using the full path `/Users/username/Applications/Android Studio/sdk/android`

Comment: Then i get "No such file or directory"

Comment: did you add an **escape character** `/Users/username/Applications/Android\ Studio/sdk/android` and what if you do `ls -l /Users/username/Applications/Android\ Studio/sdk/android`

Comment: The PATH from this SO answer fixed it:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23874792/324444