# ArgumentError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create SMTP-AUTH requested but missing user name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, localhost, actionmailer

I have problem with sending emails from localhost.
it was working on linux and now I'm trying to run my app on mac and it doesn't work already.

I have an error:

```
ArgumentError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
SMTP-AUTH requested but missing user name
```

in config/environments/development.rb:

```
#Action Mailer config
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# Send email in development mode.
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: "smtp.gmail.com",
port: "587",
domain: "mail.google.com",
authentication: "plain",
enable_starttls_auto: true,
user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USER_ID"],
password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

My env variables are good, I tried put my credential into code as well and it still doesn't work :/

I checked similiar topics but didn't found the solution.

What can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read:

> I tried put my credential into code as well and it still doesn't work :/

But have you tried replacing your var env with your gmail id/password like this ?

```
#Action Mailer config
**********
user_name: "my_username",
password: "my_password"
}
```

Just to be sure.

Comment: yes, exactly like that, "my_email@gmail.com" and "my_password".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved.

1. credentials didn't work because I havn't restarted my server (stupid laziness)
2. my env vars didn't work because I've puted them into ~.profile but it work in ~.bash_profile, [that was helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526470/trying-to-add-adb-to-path-variable-osx/19764254#19764254) (I use OS X Yosemite).