# Installing ADB on macOS

Tags: android, macos, adb

I had issues finding a good solid tutorial on how to setup ADB for Mac.

How can I add **ADB** to **macOS** in such a way that it can be used in the terminal?

**UPDATE**

For those reading this post. Yes, as the edited response says. I was at the time looking for a tutorial with all steps as a beginner level guide.

---

Unlike [Set up adb on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901692/set-up-adb-on-mac-os-x), the intention of this question is to have a tutorial with **all** of the required installation steps to get ADB on macOS.

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526470/trying-to-add-adb-to-path-variable-osx

Comment: Mine seems to be more of a step process I wouldn't say it's a duplicate. More so a different way of going about it. Specially giving a place to download the adb files.

Comment: @wesleyfranks congratulations on having such a popular question! It's one of the top search results on Google for installing ADB on Mac. Also, if you feel like my answer is satisfactory, you can show that by marking it as Accepted.

Comment: I was hoping my answer would be helpful too! LOL, guess not everyone likes your answer, but sense it is the popular answer I will mark it accepted in hopes people will see me as a team player. I'm for helping everyone get the right information so thank you @brismuth.

Comment: There is a link to the official `platform-tools` SDK package (which contains the `adb` binary) at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/adb/info

Comment: ADB might already be installed at `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/` http://stackoverflow.com/a/17901693

Comment: @AlexP. this question has 2x as many views and 4x as many answer upvotes as the question you marked it a duplicate of. It's also the top google search result for installing ADB on OS X. I'll update my answer to reference the zip on the ADB tag page, but marking this as a duplicate seems unwarranted.

Comment: @AlexP. also, as the OP pointed out, the other question is essentially asking for helping adding a line to your bash profile, whereas the point of this one is to provide a full guide.

Comment: @AlexP. why is this question closed? The other question is nothing like this one, and not nearly as helpful.

Answer (score 1613, accepted):

*Note for **zsh users**: replace all references to `~/.bash_profile` with `~/.zshrc`.*

## Option 1 - Using Homebrew

This is the easiest way and will provide automatic updates.

1. Install the [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) package manager

   ```
    /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
   ```
2. Install adb

   ```
    brew install android-platform-tools
   ```
3. Start using adb

   ```
    adb devices
   ```

## Option 2 - Manually (just the platform tools)

This is the easiest way to get a manual installation of ADB and Fastboot.

1. Delete your old installation *(optional)*

   ```
    rm -rf ~/.android-sdk-macosx/
   ```
2. Navigate to https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html and click on the `SDK Platform-Tools for Mac` link.
3. Go to your Downloads folder

   ```
    cd ~/Downloads/
   ```
4. Unzip the tools you downloaded

   ```
    unzip platform-tools-latest*.zip
   ```
5. Move them somewhere you won't accidentally delete them

   ```
    mkdir ~/.android-sdk-macosx
    mv platform-tools/ ~/.android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools
   ```
6. Add `platform-tools` to your path

   ```
    echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/.android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```
7. Refresh your bash profile (or restart your terminal app)

   ```
    source ~/.bash_profile
   ```
8. Start using adb

   ```
    adb devices
   ```

## Option 3 - Manually (with SDK Manager)

1. Delete your old installation *(optional)*

   ```
    rm -rf ~/.android-sdk-macosx/
   ```
2. Download the Mac SDK Tools from the Android developer site under ["Get just the command line tools"](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#mac-tools). Make sure you save them to your Downloads folder.
3. Go to your Downloads folder

   ```
    cd ~/Downloads/
   ```
4. Unzip the tools you downloaded

   ```
    unzip tools_r*-macosx.zip
   ```
5. Move them somewhere you won't accidentally delete them

   ```
    mkdir ~/.android-sdk-macosx
    mv tools/ ~/.android-sdk-macosx/tools
   ```
6. Run the SDK Manager

   ```
    sh ~/.android-sdk-macosx/tools/android
   ```
7. Uncheck everything but `Android SDK Platform-tools` *(optional)*

[image]

8. Click `Install Packages`, accept licenses, click `Install`. Close the SDK Manager window.

[image]

9. Add `platform-tools` to your path

   ```
    echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/.android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```
10. Refresh your bash profile (or restart your terminal app)

    ```
    source ~/.bash_profile
    ```
11. Start using adb

    ```
    adb devices
    ```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the homebrew version (I'm on Mavericks with XCode 5.0.1 with clang-500.2.79). Installation successful. adb finds my device. But when trying a `adb backup -all` I get a `Buffer Error: 10`     Installing the Android Studio and using that adb version solved my issue.

Comment: @georg that's interesting. Were they two different adb versions?

Comment: @georg I've also added steps now for a manual sdk-tools-only installation for cases like yours.

Comment: @brismuth THX. forgot to post the versions. The one that was working was `1.0.32 Revision eac51f2bb6a8-android`. The homebrew version was `1.0.32 Revision 57224c5cff69-android`.

Comment: Could you help me see what is wrong with my answer? I am sure yours is more robust, however I have a negative number for my answer when it accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Certainly! You'll find some good tips to writing answers over on meta, here's an example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question. As far as the difference between our answers, yours could be formatted to be more easily consumed. Putting code and terminal text inside code blocks and using header tags on headers helps people to find the info they need. Also, some of your steps are a bit vague, and could use some additional explanation. My answer is explicit and everything a user needs to type and run is separated so it is easy to copy and paste.

Comment: Maybe it was just me, but the SDK from Google's website (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk) does not include ADB nor Fastboot :-\ This fixed it for me, thanks!

Comment: @JoãoRochadaSilva thanks for letting me know. I'll update the manual installation portion of my guide to match the changes to the site.

Comment: Homebrew guide compared to Windows guide 8)

Comment: In case anyone opted for the brew install and it did not work, try running `source ~./bash_profile` after brew has finished.

Comment: on Sierra point 4 was redundant. Outstanding answer anyway

Comment: On Mac OS X (El Capitan) The platform-tools are in a different directory, so instead replace step 9 above with `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @Edwin looks like steps 4 and 5 were out of date with some changes Google made to the zip format, so I've updated them. If you follow the guide as it is now, step 9 is correct, and the files will be in `~/.android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/` as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Now that they are about to move android-platform-tools to cask (message: `It was migrated from homebrew/core to caskroom/cask.`), this command worked for me: `brew cask install android-platform-tools` (see also https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/pull/31126)

Comment: Good homebrew cask. Wish it was called simply `adb`, as running `brew search adb` returns 0 result. [Opened an issue on homebrew-cask repo about it](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/60253), by the way.

Comment: The update "Android SDK Platform-tools" helped me.

Comment: goat. Using brew was a disaster. Keep getting hit with ... executable already exists. Deleted like 20 things before I found this.

Comment: I think that this needs to be updated to:
brew install --cask  android-platform-tools

Answer (score 183):

If you've already installed Android Studio --

Add the following lines to the end of `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` (if using Oh My ZSH):

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Restart Terminal and you're good to go.

Comment: yeah you can use exec zsh or exec bash for restarting it :)

Comment: Had not added the last command in the terminal. This worked, after numerous searches and attempts. Thank you!

Comment: I had to add those lines to `~/.bash_profile` and it worked!

Comment: my zshrc location was at   ==>    /etc/zshrc
and by adding the mentioned path at the end of the file everything become OK.
thanks

Comment: # Here is what i ended up doing.  

`export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/"`
`export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/"`
`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

Comment: If you don't want to have to restart you terminal, simply run `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 29):

Note that if you use Android Studio and download through its SDK Manager, the SDK is downloaded to `~/Library/Android/sdk` by default, not `~/.android-sdk-macosx`.

I would rather add this as a comment to @brismuth's excellent answer, but it seems I don't have enough reputation points yet.

Answer (score 23):

## Option 3 - Using MacPorts

Analoguously to the two options (homebrew / manual) posted by @brismuth, here's the MacPorts way:

1. Install the Android SDK:

   ```
   sudo port install android
   ```
2. Run the SDK manager:

   ```
   sh /opt/local/share/java/android-sdk-macosx/tools/android
   ```
3. As @brismuth suggested, uncheck everything but `Android SDK Platform-tools` *(optional)*
4. Install the packages, accepting licenses. Close the SDK Manager.
5. Add `platform-tools` to your path; in MacPorts, they're in `/opt/local/share/java/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools`.  E.g., for bash:

   ```
   echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/share/java/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```
6. Refresh your bash profile (or restart your terminal/shell):

   ```
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```
7. Start using adb:

   ```
   adb devices
   ```

Comment: Fixed it for me. :-)

Comment: Android for Mac OS port is broken:

Answer (score 10):

1. You must download Android SDK from [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).
2. You can really put it anywhere, but the best place at least for me was right in the **YOUR USERNAME** folder root.
3. Then you need to set the path by copying the below text, but edit your username into the path, copy the text into Terminal by hitting <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd> type **terminal**.
   `export PATH = ${PATH}:/Users/**YOURUSERNAME**/android-sdk/platform-tools/`
4. Verify ADB works by hitting <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd> and type **terminal**, and type **ADB**.

There you go. You have ADB setup on MAC OS X. It works on latest MAC OS X 10.10.3.

Comment: I still don't understand why my answer isn't acceptable it's definitely a working solution. I don't understand why I have a negative vote?

Comment: hi, it's a matter of style. Your formatting is hard to read. 1. Generally writing in caps is equivalent of SCREAMING at people on the net. 2. Bolding it and bolding too much make things worse 3. This 'username' thing is not needed here, see the accepted answer to see better solution - your answer would be shorter and simpler.

You can see the accepted answer and learn from the style - how to present things, and highlight them and make it clear. I followed that and it's just simple copy/paste a few times.

Currently the accepted answer is also more complete.

Comment: I edited your answer a bit to help you start making it look good - it can still get a lot of likes :)

Comment: Ah, gotcha wasn't aware of that format issue. I believed it looked fine, but I understand that I could be wrong. Thanks for updating my answer this is apparently my most popular question (despite it being a duplicate). People can sometimes be harsh on others just trying to be apart of the community. That said, thank you for your assistance.