# android studio ADB Could not open interface: e00002c5 mac os X after install tizen studio

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, tizen

mac os X yosemite

help..I am encountering a problem with Android studio while connect to my phone debugging through USB. after installing tizen studio few days ago

> ./adb device
>
> Could not open interface: e00002c5

i was check [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/65877/what-app-or-process-can-interfere-with-adb-on-a-mac) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42177716/3358889) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650024/macbook-adb-cannot-open-interface/36662403#36662403), my problem was similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40857726/android-adb-not-detecting-device-in-mac-os-x-although-device-is-detected-by-andr) but not working for me

- error code e00002c5 means the device is already in use by another
  driver.
- some case because tizen studio was running, but i dont open tizen
  studio
- easytheter, i dont have it
- Set device in Developer mode and enable USB debugging
- Cable works well (Android file transfer automatically opens when I
  connect the device)
- Installed Java JDK 8 (before tizen instalation)
- I have done 'adb kill-server', restarted my device and Mac but still
  not working

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found weird solution -_- open tizen studio and close it make my adb work