# I have tried everything but still my device is unauthorized in adb(Mac)

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, adb

I'm using Redmi note 5 pro. I am stuck in this for the last 6 hours. Can you please help me with this

Comment: You enabled developer options on the device?

Comment: have u tried these ??

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135999/adb-not-finding-my-device-phone-macos-x

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40857726/android-adb-not-detecting-device-in-mac-os-x-although-device-is-detected-by-andr/52045579

Comment: I have turned on usb debugging, Install via USB and Turned off miui optimization. I'm using mac. I'm trying to use my phone as an Emulator in Android studio via USB. It displayed no devices. So I checked with adb and it also showed unauthorized. My Android studio shows this error https://paste.pics/8S816