# 'adb' is not recognized as a command

Tags: android, bash, macos, adb

In my new MacBook, I installed latest Android Studio. Then, in terminal, I created the .bash_profile, and added following lines to the file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk

export ANDROID_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/tools

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform_tools

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_TOOLS
```

After that, I run command `source .bash_profile`, then I type `adb` command, but get error that adb is not recognized as a command. Why? I also `echo $PATH`, I saw the `platform_tools` directory of Android sdk is there & there is adb file under that directory.

**====== UPDATE =====**

It is interesting, if I do following, it works:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/tools
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk
```

WHY? Isn't `~` above identical to `/Users/myname`? Why my original script doesn't work but the above one works? I don't understand....Please someone explain to me.

Comment: Please post the output of `find ~ -name 'adb*'`. Also, you should export `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`. [According to the NDK team](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/qZjhOaynHXc/2ux2ZZdxy2MJ), the Android tools use the variables to find things. There's also a `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` discussed in some questions, but its not documented. I still have not seen a canonical reference for it. Finally, `ANDROID_HOME` looks incorrect. Usually its something like `~/.android`. It does not point to the SDK directory.

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374085/installing-adb-on-mac-os-x) link, you can use brew to install the adb... No hassle..

Comment: @jww, I have added ndk and sdk path. I can see adb executable under my `ANDROID_HOME/platform_tools`, I don't understand what does `Usually its something ~/.android` mean.

Comment: Also worth mentioning... Bash has a "program path cache" that sometimes needs updating. Its the reason for problems like [Path not being honored?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/226149/83961) on [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/). Its a Bash issue; not an OS X issue.

Comment: typographical error - `platform_tools` vs `platform-tools`

Comment: Hey @AlexP.  Post your solution and get the 50 points.  They belong to you.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike, I do not care about the points. If that's indeed the only cause of OP's problem - the question would be off-topic and should be closed.

Comment: well, you get my vote.  well done.

Comment: Change to the folder that contains adb and do an ls -ll on the folder. Check the execute attributes are set appropriately. Also use ${HOME} instead of ~ in path. And as others have mentioned the _ vs - is a problem!

Comment: have you tried to add these exports in `.profile` file??

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the shell, `export` variable definitions can be treated differently than normal assignments — in particular, [tilde expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) might not occur at all.

If this is the case, then every unresolved tilde in a variable stays unresolved even if this variable gets expanded somewhere else. [According to the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html):

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, **parameter and variable expansion**, <…>

You might want to try this:

```
ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_HOME

export ANDROID_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/tools

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform_tools

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_TOOLS
```

If it doesn`t help, you can also try `$HOME`:

```
ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_HOME
```

Comment: @Leem.fin then apparently AlexP was right, and the question should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

This pretty fundamental stuff:
In the current directory (./) execute command "adb"
./adb (you say this works).
what you want is adb (execute command adb found from the PATH variable), if the command "adb" can be found after searching in ALL paths in the **PATH** variable, execute the command adb where it is found.
A common precursor in the path entries is "." (current directory) but is discouraged due to executable name abuse (same name in a random directory).
Different paths are separated by the path separation variable (in windows it is semicolon ";" UNIX usually colon ":" ALSO **MAC**).
Your multiple exports **SEEM** to be over writing each other, do it once with the appropriate separator ":" and all your paths in one (or **ALWAYS** include $PATH: to retain all previous exports).
it should be in ../somewhere../sdk/platform-tools/adb 
(where ever your SDK resides) export PATH=$PATH:/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools seems ok (be careful not to over-ride it[erase]).
After a re-boot all paths should be honored.
**NB**
in UNIX we have the "which adb" command which tells us where the executable resides. In Windows with tools like cygwin we can also do the same thing.
I believe Mac has  Homebrew.

Comment: that's not what the question was about

Comment: @ Alex P what is it about if not this ?

Answer (score 1):

In your example all lines work OK (but pay particular attention to `platform_tools` folder's name):

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform_tools:$ANDROID_TOOLS

source .bash_profile
adb
```

[image]

so, you've got a mistake:

```
platform_tools
```

instead of:

```
platform-tools
```

[image]

Also, you could try this solution, it works fine:

```
# print two export commands to your ~/.bash_profile
echo "export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/swift/Library/Android/sdk" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools" >> ~/.bash_profile

# Refresh bash profile (or restart Terminal.app)
source ~/.bash_profile

# Start using your adb command
adb --version
adb devices
```

Comment: THanks but please read my question, I know how to make it work.

Comment: You can use 'tilda' in a path.