# Testing Android IAB - Subscription is cancelled but purchase status is still active

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

Google has made IAB testing much simpler and when I'm testing a monthly subscription runs for 5 minutes and then I got the mail from Play Store:

> Your ... subscription from ... on Google Play has been cancelled.

But when query inventory / purchase over Play Store API, I still get

"purchaseState":0

Which means "OK". I have been waiting for a day - may be it does not work immediately - but it's still stuck at 0 / OK. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, google saves the subscription information in the cache of your phone, so the only way to solve it is cleaning the application data but of course that is not a viable solution, the other would be to update the information of the Subscriptions frequently to see if they match but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in command line to clear purchased items cache on your device:

`adb shell pm clear com.android.vending`

Comment: where is commandline?? in mac and where to put this line can u explain in detail

Comment: @shyam here is the terminal tutorial and here is the adb installation question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374085/installing-adb-on-macos

Comment: Saved my day. Need to make it as answer!