# Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug' react native app

Tags: android, react-native, build

Hi i got this error when i try to run react app on my real android device via : `react-native run-android`

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to install all 

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: upgrade com.android.tools.build:gradle to 2.3.0 and gradle to version 3.3.

Comment: @AnubhavGupta how i can upgrade gradle in terminal .. i don't use android studio just terminal

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/932083/how-do-i-upgrade-gradle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try these steps.

1. Delete node modules folder in your project.
2. Delete build folder in `android/build`
3. Close all running terminals.
4. Make sure you have installed adb drivers in your environment. If not install adb drivers. ([For macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32314718/7867613) / [For Windows](https://adb.clockworkmod.com/))
5. Open new terminal window and in your project folder run `npm install` to re-install node modules.
6. Finally run your app using `react-native run-android`

Comment: I also followed above steps and solved similar issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, make sure you run the emulator before running the commands and the emulator API level matches the targetSdk (build.gradle).