# How to connect android devices to vs code in flutter for check the code?i turned on debugging too

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, dart

I am stuck here. I connect a USB drive from my laptop to the android device but still vs code shows no device. [Image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3c10.jpg)

Comment: Few points based on your image

1. uncomment the import statement in the beginning.
2. Make sure your PC detects your mobile, enable USB debugging on your mobile.

Answer (score 4):

Considering that you have successfully installed Flutter and Dart and their respective VS Code Plugins.

There are 2 ways to do it

1. If you have a physical Android Device, you must enable USB debugging on your device and then you can connect it directly to your machine. Once the device is successfully connected and detected by your machine, then its name would appear on bottom right corner in VS Code window.
2. If you don't have a physical device, then you must create an emulator image of Android platform of your choice. The emulator image must be created from AVD manager present in Android SDK. Once the AVD image is ready and running, the name of the AVD would appear on bottom right corner of VS Code window.

If you see your device name on bottom corner of VS Code, then press F5 and wait for the app to load on the device/emulator.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways before the app is released.

1. USB Debugging
2. Wireless Debugging

   1. Connect via USB: `adb tcpip 5555`
   2. Disconnect USB, Get Phone Ip Address `Settings > About Phone > Status`.
   3. Now `adb connect <Your IP Address>`

Refer:

1. [How to connect a device with ADB over WiFi when making app with Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55076924/13431819)
2. https://appmaking.com/run-flutter-apps-on-android-device