# Is there only one way to run my Flutter app on a real Android phone?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to run my Flutter app on a real Android phone. I googled my problem and referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54444538/16124033).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526682/16124033) says I can do it using USB. But, I have a question, can I upload `.apk` file (`build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk`) to Google Drive and download `.apk` file in real Android phone and run it?

I didn't share the code because I don't think the code has anything to do with this.

Is there only one way to run my Flutter app on a real Android phone? Or, is there another way? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can upload it to google drive and install it from there.

Comment: you can create a http (or ftp) server on you machine and serve the file from there. There isn't any limit how you get the apk to the device.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways before the app is released.

1. USB Debugging
2. Wireless Debugging

   1. Connect via USB: `adb tcpip 5555`
   2. Disconnect USB, Get Phone Ip Address `Settings > About Phone > Status`.
   3. Now `adb connect <Your IP Address>`

@Credit : Harpreet Singh

Refer:

1. [How to connect a device with ADB over WiFi when making app with Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55076924/13431819)
2. https://appmaking.com/run-flutter-apps-on-android-device