# Why can't I install Flutter app in real Android phone?

Tags: android, flutter

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74663577/16124033) and here is another question related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74663577/16124033).

I have uploaded `.apk` file (`build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk`) to Google Drive and downloaded `.apk` file in real Android phone, but I can't install the application is in a real Android phone.

I downloaded the `.apk` file:

[image]

When I click on the "`app-debug.apk`" item, the following screen pops up:

[image]

When I click the install button, it loads and displays the following screen:

[image]

Also, the Android version of my Android phone is 8.1.0.

I didn't share the code because I don't think the code has anything to do with this.

Why can't I install Flutter app in real Android phone? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try installing it via `adb`?

Comment: try generate apk file again

Comment: Hi @FutureJJ thanks for your comment. What is that? Can you answer this question and share more details?

Comment: Make sure the old app is uninstalled from the device before installing the new one.

Comment: Hi @JasminSojitra thanks for your reply, I know now

Comment: @JohnJoe I tried it but got the same problem

Comment: Please post the command that you used to build the APK. If you simply uploaded the one created to run on the emulator then it won't work. You need to build for arm64.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. You can build your app from Android Studio (or another IDE) - Instead of selecting an emulator, select your own Android phone. You have to switch your phone to Developer mode.
2. Publish your app on Google play console, internal testing or closed testing, add yourself as a tester then install the app. You'll need a Developer account.