# Google Coral flashing (for first time) frozen at "Rebooting into bootloader"

Tags: macos, terminal, fastboot, google-coral

I have been following the "Get started with the dev board" page and am currently flashing my Coral for the first time using a mac as my host computer.

My screen terminal shows "request [####] was not queued to eplin-bulk," and my fastboot terminal show errors with clearing the input and output pipes, and is currently Rebooting into bootloader. It's been stuck like this for over 30 mins.

For reference, I used ([Installing ADB on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374085/installing-adb-on-macos)) instructions to download fastboot, and (https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/get-started/) instructions for every other part of setup.

This is the output from the fastboot terminal:

```
Sending 'bootloader0' (1006 KB)                    OKAY [  0.048s]

Writing 'bootloader0'                              OKAY [  0.190s]

Finished. Total time: 0.264s

Rebooting into bootloader                          OKAY [  0.024s]

Finished. Total time: 0.024s

Sending 'gpt' (33 KB)                              OKAY [  0.018s]

Writing 'gpt'                                      OKAY [  0.309s]

Finished. Total time: 0.346s

ERROR: could not clear input pipe; result e00002ed, ignoring...

ERROR: could not clear output pipe; result e0004051, ignoring....

Rebooting into bootloader
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue, but not entirely sure what it was that did it. I went back through the instructions I linked in the question, redownloaded the system image, and the flashing process was successful

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the script does not sleep long enough after rebooting the board.

In the flash.sh script, look for the sleeps following the reboots. They are at lines 74 & 79. I changed them to sleep for 10 seconds and things were good to go.

Comment: this seems to be a working solution. Note that you'll need to make sure `fastboot devices` still shows something before running `flash.sh` again. And this time you won't see `ERROR: could not clear input pipe;`