# react-native run-android not working in mac

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run the react-native application using react-native run-android but getting the error
" Failed to connect to development server using 'adb reverse':spawnSync adb ENOENT "

Also when I try to run adb devices 
-bash: adb: command not found

Comment: Did you install `adb`?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374085/installing-adb-on-macos

Comment: Yes it was installed but then I reinstalled it through brew and it is working.

Comment: fixed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60798881/3846287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue. I updated my ANDROID_HOME env variable again it worked for me.

Follow this [React-native android-setup documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started#3-configure-the-android_home-environment-variable)

ex:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
```

Windows:

set

```
ANDROID_HOME=c:/Users/whoever/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
```

Mac:

1 - Open your bash profile:

```
open .bash_profile
```

Add this to your bash_profile:

```
export ANDROID_SDK=/Users/<your_computer_name>/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=/Users/<your_computer_name>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Save and close

Compile your changes

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Please get your settings updated with latest version.