# React native failed to launch emulator

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

While trying to test the android app am creating with React native, I run into this error

```sh
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
```

I have the emulator(the AMD version) installed in the android studio.

How can I solve this problem

Comment: You might need to "start"/"run" the emulator if you haven't already. You could use the `avd list` command to see if you have any emulators running currently.

Answer (score 10):

In your scenario before running react native application you need to create emulator using Android Studio. You can view official documentation about running application on device by [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device)

Before running your project make sure you have installed **adb drivers** - [More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374085/installing-adb-on-macos)

First of all create AVD using Android Studio.

Open your project android folder using Android Studio.

**1. Click AVD Manager from Android Studio**
[image]
 **2. Click Create Virtual Device** 
[image]
 **3. Select your device from device list and click Next**
[image]
 **4. Select the android os version from the available version list and click Next**
[image]
 **5. On last keep default settings on device and click Finish**
[image]

After that you can see your available android emulator device list from AVD Manager window.

*** Before run your react native application make sure you have turn on and run the android emulator from android studio**

[image]

After that run your project using `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 3):

You can run the command `adb devices` to check if there is any device attached. It should list atleast one device for it to work

Comment: thanks, it's also working on Windows OS (CMD)

Answer (score 0):

This also may be there is not enough space to run avd, make sure enoug space in hard disk. in my case  freed atlest 9gb.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31063126)

Answer (score -1):

My answer is, If you have changed the directory of avds, you should set **ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable to the parent directory of .android.**

Here is the detail:
It seems like when you run "emulator -list-avds" in cmd, the result is empty. (be sure to first add "ANDROID_HOME" with value of your sdk directory to your user environment variable, and "%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator" in the Path too.)

After checking the official documents:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#starting
It said:
"$ emulator -list-avds

When you use this option, it displays a list of AVD names from your Android home directory. Note that you can override the default home directory by setting the ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable: the root of the user-specific directory where all configuration and AVD content is stored. You could set the environment variable in the terminal window before launching a virtual device, or you could set it through your user settings in the operating system."

and in another page:
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables#envar
it said:
"Some older tools, such as Android Studio 4.3 and below, do not read ANDROID_USER_HOME. To override the user preferences location for those older tools set ANDROID_SDK_HOME to the parent directory you would like the .android directory to be created under."

So I guess the reason is "npx react-native run-android" will invoke "emulator -list-avds" to find the emulator. And "emulator" is really an older tools, so ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable is necessay.

And if all goes well, you really don't need to run android studio before run "npx reactive-native run-android".