# React native emulator failed to start in windows10

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

Does anyone knows how to fix this issue?

This is the exact command and result in windows 10.

```
react-native run-android

> info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can
> disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag. Jetifier found 864 file(s) to
> forward-jetify. Using 4 workers... info Starting JS server... 'adb' is
> not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
> batch file. info Launching emulator... error Failed to launch
> emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator
> -list-avds`. warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
```

This is the actual screen shot.
[image]

Comment: this is not an error, error is something else. please share the complete screenshot of your npm console or code.

Comment: So did you create android emulator device using AVD Manager ? If yes, did you run the emulator before run react native ?

Comment: I think my answer on this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60266497/react-native-failed-to-launch-emulator/60273686#60273686