# Launching appium server programmatically throws server-side error Could not find 'adb' in PATH

Tags: appium, liferay-service-builder

While launch appium server manually this issue doesnt occur.

Error log

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb' in PATH. Please set the ANDROID_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variables to the corect Android SDK root directory path.
```

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'INSML-0VLLVCF', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c3f:fa48:d75f:bc45%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_251'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb' in PATH. Please set the ANDROID_HOME or ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variables to the corect Android SDK root directory path.
at getResponseForW3CError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/errors.js:804:9)
at asyncHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/protocol/protocol.js:388:37)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'INSML-0VLLVCF', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c3f:fa48:d75f:bc45%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_251'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver

Answer (score 0):

Run `which aapt` in terminal and check the output. Most likely it is empty.

If you didn't install adb, you can follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32314718/4103101)

If you install it, then probably you didn't set path properly: run `cat ~/.bash_profile` and make sure to set path to ANDROID_HOME, assuming you did default path installation

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<your_username>/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/<sdk_version>:$PATH
```

You can check [official Appium docs](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/environment.md) about environment issues troubleshoot

Comment: Is it not enough to set ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools  and ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin?
Note: Launching manually does not show any errors - whereas launching programmatically throws this error.

Comment: Have you tried to follow steps in answer? Launching manually doesn't mean it will work via terminal

Comment: Yes, I added all these environment variable again but programmatically launching appium did not work. 
Note : Tried launching appium manually and starting the execution in the port defined works fine